# .env VUE_APP_ variable json?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

Starting to use the vue cli 3 and ran into a use-case I can't seem to find an answer for.

How can I set an environment variable via a .env file (ie, .env.development, .env.production, etc) that exposes a JSON object? Additionally, is there a way to load an external files contents into an environment variable (i.e., require)?

Appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution to solve my own issue...

Although the previous answers are viable I didn't want to have to JSON.parse every time I wanted to use the JSON in the environment variable.

The approach I took was to store in each environment-specific file (i.e., .env-development, .env-production, .env-test) a file path to a file containing the JSON. For example...

```
VUE_APP_JSON_FILE=./.env.development.json-data
```

This file would contain the raw JSON...

Then in my vue.config.js I used the webpack DefinePlugin to load up the file and make it available via a global variable. For example...

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     VUE_APP_JSON: JSON.stringify(process.env.VUE_APP_JSON_FILE)
})
```

Defining the new variable will make the json available as an object where throughout my app I can simply reference VUE_APP_JSON.property. This saves me from having to JSON.parse the variable all throughout my app.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Vue is a JS framework that doesn't support JSON configuration files... Sense, it makes none.

Answer (score 1):

You can 
stringObj = JSON.stringfy(YourJson),
Then save this string inside the VUE_APP_SOME_KEY_NAME.

but when you'll use it you'll have to JSON.parse () it first.

So, you cannot directly store a json object in a key value .dotEnv file.

Another option is to load these json files Base on process.env.NODE_ENV.

    `` like: require (`config.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js) ``

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish which profile using dot `.` (as `.env.production` or `.env.development`) and the format must be KEY=value, you can't put a json object here, only strings, but you can use `JSON.parse` in your code to unserialize any string in the file.

Vue cli will only allow access to environment variables that starts with `VUE_APP_` and to access, `process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET`

You can find it and more in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode)